# Docker Compose Build Error /lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

**Problem: Docker Compose Build Error /lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0**

**Environment:**

Docker
Docker Compose
Python
Django

**Issue Description:**

I encountered an error when working with the new version of Docker Compose. Previously, using the older version, the command docker-compose up -d --build worked seamlessly. However, after updating to the latest Docker Desktop version, which includes the embedded "docker compose" (new version), the same command docker compose up -d --build results in an error related to /lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0.

**Error Details:**

The specific error points to an issue with the library file /lib/libpython3.8.so.1.0.

**Seeking Assistance:**

If anyone has experienced a similar error or has insights into resolving this issue, your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You should add more details when asking a question, so that others can reproduce the issue. For example, a `ls -l` of that `.so` file, or what `file` says about it, and where you got it from. See [ask]. Also, you can answer your own questions, but don't put an answer in the question, post it as answer. That way it can get separate votes, and others can post alternative solutions. Check the [tour] for details.